# Boost ASIO SSL handshake failure

Tags: c++, macos, boost, openssl, boost-asio

When attempting to securely connect to a remote IMAP server using Boost ASIO, the server handshake fails on every connection. The exception message reads:

```
handshake: unregistered scheme (STORE routines) [asio.ssl:369098857]
```

My code is below (`url` is a `std::string_view` containing the host URL):

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
using SSLSocket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;

boost::asio::io_context context;
ssl::context ssl_context(ssl::context::tls);
SSLSocket socket(context, ssl_context);

ssl_context.set_default_verify_paths();

tcp::resolver resolver(context);
auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(url, "993");
boost::asio::connect(socket.next_layer(), endpoints);
socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
socket.set_verify_callback(ssl::host_name_verification(url.data()));
socket.handshake(SSLSocket::client);
```

The code immediately throws an exception on the final line, which is a blocking synchronous handshake.

The prior two lines set up host name verification, similar to how it's done [in the official ASIO tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html). These checks seem to be causing an issue, however, because when they are removed the handshake succeeds. Obviously, this is not a good solution.

After stepping through some of ASIO's internals, I found that the last three lines of the above snippet could be replaced by:

```
SSL_set_verify(socket.native_handle(), SSL_VERIFY_PEER, nullptr);
socket.handshake(SSLSocket::client);
```

and the same error occurs. `SSL_set_verify` is an OpenSSL function, and the fact that setting a null callback directly causes the same issue makes me think that the issue is with my system's OpenSSL environment and not ASIO or the host name verification callback. However, I have not been able to determine what exactly the error means and what could be causing it.

Here is a list of things I have tried while troubleshooting:

1. **Load the system's certificate (.pem) file explicitly** Thinking maybe ASIO and/or OpenSSL's were not able to load the right certificates to do the validation, I found my system's (a Mac) certificate file at `/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem`. I then inserted the following line:

   ```
   ssl_context.load_verify_file("/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem");
   ```

   directly after `set_default_verify_paths()` is called. My program loads this certificate file without complaining, but it doesn't fix the handshake error.
2. **Use a different version of OpenSSL** At first I was using Apple's system version of OpenSSL (which is really LibreSSL 2.8.3). I then rebuilt my code using the Homebrew package manager's version of OpenSSL (OpenSSL 3.0.4). This also did not fix the issue, even when I tried calling `load_verify_file` as in point 1.
3. **Sanity check using the OpenSSL command-line tool** To make sure my network connection and URL/port number were correct, I tried connecting to the IMAP server over SSL using the following command:

   ```
    openssl s_client -connect my.url.com:993 -crlf -verify 1
   ```

   and it worked fine, connecting to the IMAP server and enabling me to send/receive IMAP responses.

Has anyone encountered similar issues when using OpenSSL and ASIO? I'm not very familiar with setting up an SSL/TLS connection, but I don't see what could be causing the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `openssl s_client -connect my.url.com:993 -crlf -verify 1` succeeds there is not a lot that seems wrong. One thing catches my eye: I'd configure the context *before* constructing an SSL stream from it:

```
ssl::context ssl_context(ssl::context::tls);

ssl_context.set_default_verify_paths();

SSLSocket socket(context, ssl_context);
```

Also, `openssl` likely uses [SNI extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication):

```
// Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(socket.native_handle(), hostname.c_str()))
{
    throw boost::system::system_error(
        ::ERR_get_error(), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
}
```

Finally, make sure the `url` string view contains correct data, **notably** that it's a valid hostname **and** null-terminated string. In this case I'd prefer to use a string representation that guarantees null-termination:

### Summary

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
using SSLSocket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;


int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    ssl::context ssl_context(ssl::context::tls);

    ssl_context.set_default_verify_paths();

    SSLSocket socket(context, ssl_context);

    tcp::resolver r(context);
    std::string hostname = "www.example.com";
    auto endpoints = r.resolve(hostname, "443");
    boost::asio::connect(socket.next_layer(), endpoints);
    socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    socket.set_verify_callback(ssl::host_name_verification(hostname));

    // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
    if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(socket.native_handle(), hostname.c_str()))
    {
        throw boost::system::system_error(
            ::ERR_get_error(), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
    }

    socket.handshake(SSLSocket::client);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I manged to make it work with this:

```
ssl_context.load_verify_file("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt");
```

so pointing to the ca-bundle file instead of the cert file.

Answer (score 0):

I have also some challenge with this handshake in boost asio. I am using it in a FileMaker Plugin, and when it comes to this line:

```
namespace net = boost::asio;
..
..
stream.handshake(net::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client, ec);
```

It consequently crash the whole application.
After trying for hours, changing the setup, googling, and reading the documentation, I put the method into a small stand-alone application made like a command-line utility to test it in a isolated environment. Having all the same boost version (1.82.0) and the same openSSL libraries (3.1.4) in both the plugin code and test application.

In the test application, it works as expected. The code retrieve data from the server. In the plugin with the same code, FileMaker crash.

Below you ca see the crash log snippet, and also the code of the test application.

**Crash log**

```
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   FileMaker Pro Advanced                 0x10a6f7b64 boost::system::error_category::equivalent(boost::system::error_code const&, int) const + 4
1   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116ce2f4d boost::system::detail::failed_impl(int, boost::system::error_category const&) + 93 (error_category.hpp:217)
2   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116ce2ea5 boost::system::error_code::error_code(int, boost::system::error_category const&) + 53 (error_code.hpp:129)
3   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116ce2dd3 boost::system::error_code::error_code(int, boost::system::error_category const&) + 35 (error_code.hpp:130)
4   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d0ee6d boost::asio::error::make_error_code(boost::asio::error::misc_errors) + 45 (error.hpp:354)
5   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d11acf boost::system::error_code::error_code<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>(boost::asio::error::misc_errors, boost::system::detail::enable_if<(is_error_code_enum<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>::value) || (std::is_error_code_enum<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>::value), void>::type*) + 63 (error_code.hpp:150)
6   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d11a83 boost::system::error_code::error_code<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>(boost::asio::error::misc_errors, boost::system::detail::enable_if<(is_error_code_enum<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>::value) || (std::is_error_code_enum<boost::asio::error::misc_errors>::value), void>::type*) + 35 (error_code.hpp:149)
7   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d10612 boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::map_error_code(boost::system::error_code&) const + 50 (engine.ipp:240)
8   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d1024f unsigned long boost::asio::ssl::detail::io<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, boost::asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op>(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>&, boost::asio::ssl::detail::stream_core&, boost::asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op const&, boost::system::error_code&) + 607 (io.hpp:81)
9   ACF_plugin_db                          0x116d0ffbc boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> >::handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type, boost::system::error_code&) + 76 (stream.hpp:437)
10  ACF_plugin_db                          0x116cdf364 boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> >::handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type) + 52 (stream.hpp:420)
11  ACF_plugin_db                          0x116cde1de SendSoapRequest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 1710 (DocServiceXML.cpp:256)
```

**The Working Source of the test application that has the same code as the plugin**

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  test-boost-ssl
//
//  Created by Ole Kristian Ek Hornnes on 02/11/2023.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>

namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;


struct httpResponse {
    int StatusCode;
    std::string ResultText;
};

httpResponse SendPostRequest(const std::string& xurl, const std::string& post_data) {
    net::io_context ioc;
    std::string url = xurl;
    // Determine the scheme (http or https), hostname, and path
    std::string scheme, hostname, path;
    int port = 0;
    httpResponse httpResult;
    
    if (url.substr(0, 5) == "https") {
        scheme = "https";
        port = 443;
        url = url.substr(8); // Remove "https://"
    } else if (url.substr(0, 4) == "http") {
        scheme = "http";
        port = 80;
        url = url.substr(7); // Remove "http://"
    }
    
    size_t slashPos = url.find('/');
    if (slashPos != std::string::npos) {
        hostname = url.substr(0, slashPos);
        path = url.substr(slashPos);
    } else {
        hostname = url;
        path = "/";
    }
    
    bool useSSL = (scheme == "https");
    
    // These objects perform I/O
    
    try {
        
        if ( useSSL ) {
            // Set up SSL context and stream
            // Set up SSL context (only if using SSL)
            
            net::io_context xxx;
            tcp::resolver resolver(xxx);
            // tcp::socket socket(ioc);
            net::ssl::context sslContext(net::ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
            // sslContext.set_options(net::ssl::context::default_workarounds);
            
      /*      sslContext.set_options(net::ssl::context::no_sslv2);
            sslContext.set_options(net::ssl::context::no_sslv3);
            sslContext.set_options(net::ssl::context::tlsv12);*/
            
            sslContext.set_default_verify_paths();
            net::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> stream = {xxx, sslContext };
      
            // Resolve the hostname and port
            auto it = resolver.resolve(hostname, std::to_string(port));
          // std::cout << "resolver " << std::string(it) << std::endl;
            boost::system::error_code ec;
           
            net::connect(stream.next_layer(), it, ec);
            
            if (ec) {
                std::stringstream err;
                err << "Error during SSL connect: " << ec << std::endl;
                httpResult.ResultText = err.str();
                httpResult.StatusCode = -2;
                return httpResult;
            }
            // stream.set_verify_mode(net::ssl::verify_peer);
            // Perform the SSL handshake
            
            try {
                stream.handshake(net::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client, ec);
            } catch (const std::exception &e)  {
                std::stringstream err;
                err << "Error during SSL handshake: " << e.what() << "ec: " << ec << std::endl;
                httpResult.ResultText = err.str();
                httpResult.StatusCode = -2;
                return httpResult;
            }
            
            if (ec) {
                std::stringstream err;
                err << "Error during SSL Handshake: " << ec << std::endl;
                httpResult.ResultText = err.str();
                httpResult.StatusCode = -3;
                return httpResult;
            }
            
            std::string agent ("ACF_Plugin for FileMaker ver. ");
            // agent += std::string (PLUGIN_VERSION);
            // Set up an HTTPS POST request
            http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::post, path, 11};
            req.set(http::field::host, hostname);
            req.set(http::field::user_agent, agent);
            req.set(http::field::content_type, "text/xml");
           //  req.set(http::field::soapaction, SoapAction);
            
            req.body() = post_data;
            req.prepare_payload();
            
            // Send the HTTP request
            http::write(stream, req);
            
            // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
            boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            
            // Declare a container to hold the response
            http::response<http::string_body> res;
            
            // Receive the HTTP response
            http::read(stream, buffer, res);
            // Convert the response to a std::string and return it
            // Check the HTTP status code and set StatusCode accordingly
            httpResult.StatusCode = static_cast<int>(res.result_int());
            httpResult.ResultText = res.body();
            return httpResult;
        } else {
            tcp::socket socket(ioc);
            tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
            // Resolve the hostname and port
            auto results = resolver.resolve(hostname, std::to_string(port));
            boost::asio::connect(socket, results.begin(), results.end());
            
            
            // Set up an HTTP POST request
            http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::post, path, 11};
            req.set(http::field::host, hostname);
            req.set(http::field::user_agent, "MyClient/1.0");
            req.set(http::field::content_type, "text/xml");
          /*  if (SoapAction != "" ) {
                req.set(http::field::soapaction, SoapAction);
            } */
            req.body() = post_data;
            req.prepare_payload();
            
            // Send the HTTP request
            http::write(socket, req);
            
            // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
            boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            
            // Declare a container to hold the response
            http::response<http::string_body> res;
            
            // Receive the HTTP response
            http::read(socket, buffer, res);
            // Convert the response to a std::string and return it
            // Check the HTTP status code and set StatusCode accordingly
            httpResult.StatusCode = static_cast<int>(res.result_int());
            httpResult.ResultText = res.body();
            return httpResult;
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::stringstream err;
        err << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        httpResult.ResultText = err.str();
        httpResult.StatusCode = -1;
        return httpResult;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    std::string url;
    if (argc != 2) {
       // std::cerr << "Usage: postService <URL>" << std::endl;
       //  return 1;
        url = "https://myserver.no/wsx/doc/";
    } else {
        url = argv[1];
    }
    
    std::string post_data = "TEST\n\n"; // You can set your POST data here
    
    httpResponse result = SendPostRequest(url, post_data);
    
    std::cout << "URL: " << url << std::endl;
    std::cout << "HTTP Status Code: " << result.StatusCode << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response Body:\n" << result.ResultText << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output when testing that shows communication, I got a soap-fault, but since I didn't actually send any valid soap request, its expected. However, it shows that the function exchange data with the server.

```
URL: https://myserver.no/ws/doc/
HTTP Status Code: 500
Response Body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: I solved the issue using the curl easy library instead. Now it works stable from the FileMaker Plugin.